# Number of Distinct Integers in Base-3

Tags: combinatorics, binary-operations, arithmetic-progressions

**Given:**

- An integer $A$ and a natural number $K$.
- XOR operation in **base-3** on bits **$x \ and \ y$** is defined as follows, $$ x\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}y=1,⇔  x=y \\x\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}y=0, ⇔ x ≠y$$

**To find:** Number of distinct integers $B$ in **base-3** subjected to following conditions:

- No of bits in number **base-3** representation of $A$ and $B$ are same.
- No of $0$ bits in resultant XOR of $A$ and $B$ in *base-3* <= $K$
- The number **base-3** representation of $B = b_{n-1}b_{n-2}....b_1b_0$ **doesn't** contain any triplets $(i,j,k)$ such that

  1. $2*j = i+k$

     $b_i=b_j=b_k$

Comment: Please tell us what you have done yourself.

Comment: Can you give some context for this problem? Is it part of another problem which you are trying to solve?

Comment: Posting [ongoing contest questions](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/DEVGOSTR) is bad enough. Trying to disguise them is worse. Please see [our policy on contest problems](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774).